# WCF - The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I am using an external WSDL file for a WCF Service.

```
<wsdl:service n<wsdl:service name="CommonService">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ICommonService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ICommonService">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:1371/CommonService.wsdl"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

When i add a service reference to this servie, i get an error in the client as Method Not Allowed.

But when i remove the above code from WSDL file and replace the same with this, it works fine. Whats the problem. Can anyone identify the reson behind this.

```
<wsdl:service name="CommonService">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_ICommonService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_ICommonService">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:1371/Service.svc"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think that it is the fact you don't expose a handler for .wsdl extension in IIS.  Or you do not have a way to map that extension on.  Usually, the wsdl in a WCF service is found at `.svc?wsdl`.

Sorry if I'm stating the obvious, but the reason looks to be changing the location from this:

`http://localhost:1371/CommonService.wsdl`

To this:

`http://localhost:1371/Service.svc`